# [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,0)];

Tags: iphone, sqlite, nsstring, nsnumber

i m using sqlite

i am geting a return value frmo DB in this manner

```
returnCount = [NSString  stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,0)];
```

but the returend value is an integer value.
how can i get a int value instead of paasing it in string...like this thing here

```
[NSString  stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,0)];
```

is for string, is there any way to get it in "integer" right away, otherwise i need to cast it.

suggestions please.

Comment: In future posting to SO, please put four spaces before each line of a block of code, and surround inline code fragments with backticks.  This makes the code examples much more readable.  See [Stack Overflow Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer, since it seems you *know* it's going to be an integer count, read it as an int with `sqlite3_column_int()`.

That said, you may want to refactor your code after you drop in [FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).  FMDB will do the conversion for you when pulling data from integer or float columns.  In your case, the result of a `SELECT count(*) FROM myTable...` would be a a single column of type integer and the `[resultSet valueForkey:@"count"]` will be an `NSNumber` as expected.

Comment: .."sqlite3_column_int()."  dat worked for me...thanks a ton man

Comment: To be fair, the simplest way is to just use Core Data. ;)

Comment: @bbum, Yes, Core Data rocks, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: Sometimes there is an an answer and a meta-answer.   The meta-answer is for folks new to the platform and/or new to SQLite to stop wasting their time and just use Core Data.  It will require less engineering effort over the lifetime of a project.  There are legitimate reasons not to, but they are pretty few and far between.